# How can I hook into the explorer directory calls in windows to determine when a new directory is opened?

Tags: c#, winapi

If you use a tool like Process Monitor, you can see that when a directory is opened, explorer.exe performs a `DirectoryQuery`. I don't know if `DirectoryQuery` is specific to procmon, but I'm trying to see if I can capture those calls within C#. Or determine if there are any Win32 APIs I can PInvoke to get this info.

[image]

There are other tools like [Clover](http://ejie.me) that also do this. The functionality I'm trying to replicate is basically the same as Clover. Where I would redirect new directories to my application instead of Explorer.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think Clover redirects anything. Please clarify, do you want to hook into Explorer or replace Explorer?

Comment: Maybe `IExplorerBrowser::Advise` might be relevant.

Comment: @Anders Replace Explorer. I'm not sure how Clover does it. But it's interesting because when I have Clover installed and I open a directory, procmon only shows the explorer calls. It only shows Clover doing something of it's closed.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: "Clover is an extension of the Windows Explorer" so I don't think it replaces it.

Comment: @Anders It may not completely replace it, but it effectively does. When it's installed, all directories are opened in Clover. You never see the Explorer window.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own File Explorer application then you can use the [`IExplorerBrowser`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110325-00/?p=11133/) object to do 90% of the work for you. [Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx) a new default verb for the `Directory` and `Folder` ProgIds.

If you want to hook into Explorers File Explorer windows then you must implement a [browser helper object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(v=vs.85).aspx) ([C# if you must](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19971/how-to-attach-to-browser-helper-object-bho-with-c)) and [tweak it so it only loads in Explorer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/04/11/browser-helper-objects-for-windows-explorer/).

DWebBrowserEvents2 will tell you about navigation events.

Comment: I'm using the `ExplorerBrowser` control from the WindowsAPICodePack and it works well. The navigation stuff is all there. I'm just now trying to see how to make directories open in my app instead of the Windows Explorer window.